# Combining and minifying CSS/JS files

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, web-deployment, minify

I'm writing a Chrome extension for which I remotely load CSS and JavaScript files. I'm looking for a tool that will combine and minify my CSS files into 1 file and my JS files into 1 file. Bonus points if it can automatically detect changed files and minify on its own so that all I have to do is upload the files to my server for testing without having to explicitly process the files via the command line or some such.

Does anyone have any favorite tools that can do this?

Comment: http://gulpjs.com/, http://gruntjs.com/

Comment: If this question is off-topic, where does it belong? If you're going to downvote me, at least offer a resolution. I obviously didn't know it would be off-topic to begin with sheesh

Comment: If your addressee is me, I didn't *vote.

Comment: @Vohuman I didn't think you voted. I just wanted to comment on the downvote in case that person gets a notification. Thanks for your suggestion, though! I think I'd mark it as the answer (if you'd provide it as the answer), because gruntjs looks really promising.

Comment: Since you're asking where this will be on-topic, there's [softwarerecs.se]. Here it's clear-cut off-topic.

Comment: Thank you, @Xan. This community has really gotten out of control. When I started using it, people didn't close questions without giving a suggestion or resolution to help out the asker. There are too many people with the power to close things willy nilly. How am I supposed to learn if you just shut me down in 10 minutes?

Comment: Are people just trying to earn reputation points?

Comment: As the asker, what am I supposed to do when my question is closed? Guess at where this question would be on-topic? Why do I have to explicitly ASK moderators for this kind of information?

Comment: @Vohuman and all the other "moderators" out there, do you have an answer for me?

Comment: You can also use Sprockets. It doesn't do the detecting stuff you mentioned, but it's relatively straightforward. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576034/getting-sprockets-to-minify-css-js-while-not-in-a-rails-rack-app

Comment: @user3827303 It might be straightforward to you, but I obviously thought it was really confusing because I took the time to write a question about it. How is anyone supposed to learn using SO if we're just going to dismiss it as "the answer is obvious. Go look for it."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grunt for that.

You can minify, combine, and also watch on files for changes.

Check it out here: http://gruntjs.com/