# Getting Sprockets to minify CSS/JS while not in a Rails/Rack app

Tags: javascript, css, minify, sprockets

I'm trying to use Sprockets to combine and minify my JavaScript and CSS files outside of the Rails and Rack context. So far, I'm able to combine them into a single file, but now I'm trying to run the JS compressor and the CSS compressor on those files.

I followed the Sprockets README's instructions (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#minifying-assets), but I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `compress' for :uglify:Symbol
```

Here is my complete rakefile:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'pathname'
require 'logger'
require 'fileutils'
require 'uglifier'

Bundler.require

ROOT        = Pathname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
LOGGER      = Logger.new(STDOUT)
BUNDLES     = %w( combined.css combined.js )
BUILD_DIR   = ROOT.join("dist")
SOURCE_DIR  = ROOT.join("src")

task :compile do
  sprockets = Sprockets::Environment.new(ROOT) do |env|
    env.logger = LOGGER
    env.append_path SOURCE_DIR.join('javascripts').to_s
    env.append_path SOURCE_DIR.join('stylesheets').to_s
    env.js_compressor = :uglify
  end

  BUNDLES.each do |bundle|
    assets = sprockets.find_asset(bundle)
    prefix, basename = assets.pathname.to_s.split('/')[-2..-1]
    FileUtils.mkpath BUILD_DIR.join(prefix)

    assets.write_to(BUILD_DIR.join(prefix, basename))
  end
end
```

I've tried the following (spoiler alert: they don't work):

1. `env.js_compressor = :uglifier`
2. `env.js_compressor = Uglifier`
3. `env.js_compressor = Uglify`

And I get still get a `NoMethodError` for `compress` for each one.

What is the correct way to enable JS compression? What about CSS? (I am experiencing the similar issues there.)

======
In addition to the answer marked below, please note this:

For anyone who is curious, you'd have instantiate your compressor and make sure it responds to `compress`:

```
env.js_compressor = YUI::JavaScriptCompressor.new  
env.css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new
```

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such! I've noticed that a lot of users will comment with what I'd consider to be the answer to my question, so I'm going to preemptively request that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out (example below), and it worked for me. I would suspect that you have an outdated version of Sprockets, since the shorthand minifier notation you want to use was introduced quite recently in version 2.7.0. I would do a `gem upgrade` and hopefully that fixes it.

---

**Example Rakefile** (in a directory containing an unminified `non-min.js` file, after running `rake compile` a minified `min.js` file was generated):

```
require 'sprockets'

ROOT = Pathname(File.dirname(__FILE__))

task :compile do
  sprockets = Sprockets::Environment.new(ROOT) do |env|
    env.append_path './'
    env.js_compressor = :uglify
  end

  assets = sprockets.find_asset("non-min.js")
  assets.write_to("./min.js")
end
```

---

*Update*: To verify my answer above, I installed an older version of Sprockets (v2.6.0) and got the same error message as you did.

Comment: Oooohhh interesting. That's a really good point. I do have an older version of Sprockets. I wonder what the syntax is for 2.6.0.... Thanks so much!!